# Why redux-observable isn't working without redux-thunk?

Tags: reactjs, redux-observable

I followed the docs completely and always got

> Actions must be plain objects

If I put thunk in `applyMiddleware` with `epicMiddleware` everything works

```
// src/store/index.js

import { createStore, combineReducers, applyMiddleware } from 'redux'
import { createEpicMiddleware, combineEpics } from 'redux-observable'
import thunk from 'redux-thunk'
import users from './users/reducer'
import countEpic from './users/epics'

const epicMiddleware = createEpicMiddleware()

const store = createStore(
  combineReducers({
    users,
  }),
  applyMiddleware(thunk, epicMiddleware)
)

epicMiddleware.run(combineEpics(countEpic))

export default store
```

```
// src/store/users/epics.js

import { mapTo } from 'rxjs/operators'
import { ofType } from 'redux-observable'

const countEpic = action$ =>
  action$.pipe(
    ofType('CLICK'),
    mapTo({ type: 'INCREMENT' })
  )

export default countEpic
```

Comment: What do your action creators look like?

Comment: @DannyDelott Hi! I don't have any. The action object that, I suppose, should be dispatched by the countEpic is in mapTo